# Linked list in data stucture

Tags: linked-list

I am really struggling with this problem.
It is about the linked list in data structure.

There is a file which name is `example.txt`.

```
USA
Japan
China
Korea
Canada
```

I want to write a new file like below using linked list

```
Canada
Korea
China
Japan
USA
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024

typedef struct _node Node;

struct _node {
    char* data;
    Node *next;
};

typedef struct _list {
    Node *cur;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
}List;


int createNode(List *lp, char* data);

int createNode(List *L, char* data)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (L->head == NULL && L->tail == NULL)
        L->head = L->tail = newNode;
    else {
        L->tail->next = newNode;
        L->tail = newNode;
    }

    L->cur = newNode;
}

void printNodes(List *L)
{
    Node *p = L->head;

    while (p != NULL) {
         printf("%s\n", p->data);
         p = p->next;
    }

}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char file_name1[128], file_name2[128];
    char line[MAX_LEN];
    //create list
    List* input_list = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    input_list->cur = NULL;
    input_list->head = NULL;
    input_list->tail = NULL;

    fopen_s(&fp1,"Example.txt", "r"); //open the input file

    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("file open is not successful\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fopen_s(&fp2, "Example2.txt", "w");
    int cw = 0;

    while (cw !=5) {
        fscanf_s(fp1, "%s", line,sizeof(line));
        createNode(input_list, line);
        cw++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printNodes(input_list);


    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

But I don't know what's wrong in this code.
It prints just like this.

```
Canada
Canada
Canada
Canada
Canada
```

Could you help me?

Comment: for troubleshooting purpose try to print the data when creating new node ..

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning same address of array(line) to all node of linked list.
thats why all node of linked list pointing to same address which has value of last word read from file.
To solve this first allocate space using malloc to pointer(*data) and then copy data

```
int createNode(List *L, char* data)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    int len = 0;
    while (*(data + len) != '\0')len++;
    newNode->data = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(newNode->data, data);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (L->head == NULL && L->tail == NULL)
        L->head = L->tail = newNode;
    else {
        L->tail->next = newNode;
        L->tail = newNode;
    }

    L->cur = newNode;
}
```